# Android pull-to-refresh show loading footer at start

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

I am using the old version of Android [PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) library. It works fine for triggering loading when over scrolling.

However, I want to show the loading footer view when I first enter my activity. I tried many times but still cannot find a correct way.

Is there anybody could help me out?

Comment: try to set it to show footer with a delay of 300-500 millis,sometimes it doesn't have enough time to initialise

Comment: Thanks! That really works! Please post an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try to set it to show footer with a delay of 300-500 millis,sometimes it doesn't have enough time to initialise

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mPullRefreshGridView.setRefreshing(true);
        }
    }, 500);
```

this solved the problem to me

Comment: Thanks, it really works, and I even have tried similar approach as post a runnable with ZERO delay, and it takes no effect. It is a weird bug.

Comment: I know i also had problems with this :)

Comment: isn't there an event for when it finished initializing?

Comment: Nope, try to use the new view SwipeToRefreshLayout from support.v4 library

Answer (score 6):

Set PullToRefreshListView mode:

```
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
ptr:ptrMode="pullFromEnd"
ptr:ptrAnimationStyle="rotate"
/>
```

call

```
getRefreshableListView().setRefreshing();
```

where getRefreshableListView() is your method that finds actual PullToRefreshListView.
After initial loading of your data don't forget to call

```
getRefreshableListView().onRefreshComplete();
```

if setRefreshing() does not work, try using postDelayed():

```
getRefreshableListView().postDelayed(new Runnable() { getRefreshableListView().setRefreshing();}, 200);
```

Comment: I have already called mPullRefreshGridView.setRefreshing(); in my Activity's onCreate(), does not work

Comment: Thanks, reputations for you.

Comment: Sorry, Eddy gave the answer earlier than you.